# Does uniform convergence happen in continuous time Markov Chain?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose $X_t$ is a continuous time Markov Chain with countable (not necessarily finite) state space $S$. We know that $\lim_{h\to0+}\dfrac{1-p_{ii}(h)}{h}=q_i\in [0,\infty]$.

Suppose $q_i<\infty$ for all $i$. Then is it true that the above convergence is uniform in the sense that, given any $\epsilon>0$, does there exist a single $h_0$ such that for $0<h<h_0$ we have $|\dfrac{1-p_{ii}(h)}{h}-q_i|<\epsilon$ for all states $i$?

Comment: Of course not, consider a birth chain which jumps from $j-1$ to $j$ at rate $j$., for every positive $j$

Comment: I am yet to encounter birth death chains, so I will take your answer at face value. Thanks!

Comment: ?? Thus you have no concrete examples at hand when thinking about continuous time discrete space Markov chains? Scary...

Comment: My introduction to CTMC has been through a rather theoretical and axiomatic approach. Examples should (hopefully) follow. But you're right, it IS important to keep concrete examples at hand.

Comment: Interesting. Where do they proceed like this?